# How can I increase the performance of this...Why is there no such thing as a LazyZStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm loading a stack of cards to be swiped through (like tinder), but as it's held in a ZStack, all of the cards are loaded at once. I plan on having hundreds of cards, so I expect that this will start to be a drain on performance. How can I tweak my code to make the cards load as needed? I wish there was a LazyZStack.

Here is an image of the ContentView ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYgIA.png

Here is the main ContentView Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let cards = Card.data.shuffled()
    @State var isHelp = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                AnimatedBackground()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .blur(radius: 25)
                VStack {
                    //Top Stack
                    Spacer()
                    TopStack()
                    //Card
                    ZStack {
                        ForEach(cards, id: \.id) { index in
                            CardView(card: index)
//                                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10)
                                .padding(8)
                        }
                    }
                    //Bottom Stack
                    BottomStack()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the CardView code

```
struct CardView: View {
    @State var card: Card
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("myBlue")
            Text("\(card.text)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
        
        .cornerRadius(20)
        // Step 1 - ZStack follows the coordinate of the card model
        .offset(x: card.x, y: card.y)
        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: card.degree))
        // Step 2 - Gesture recognizer updaets the coordinate calues of the card model
        .gesture (
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    // user is dragging the view
                    withAnimation(.default) {
                        
                        card.x = value.translation.width
                        card.y = value.translation.height
                        card.degree = 7 * (value.translation.width > 0 ? 1 : -1)
                    }
                }
            
                .onEnded { value in 
                    // do something when the user stops dragging
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 50, damping: 8, initialVelocity: 0)) {
                        switch value.translation.width {
                        case 0...100:
                            card.x = 0; card.degree = 0; card.y = 0
                        case let x where x > 100:
                            card.x = 500; card.degree = 12
                        case (-100)...(-1):
                            card.x = 0; card.degree = 0; card.y = 0;
                        case let x where x < -100:
                            card.x = -500; card.degree = -12
                        default: card.x = 0; card.y = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            
        )
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! I'm still new to coding and I'm excited to hear what you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

A LazyZStack makes no sense because you can't scroll into your screen.

Instead you could keep track of the index of the card on the top, and filter the array to draw only a few more, depending on what your stack looks like.

Whenever a card is dismissed, you would update this index and the list of rendered cards would change.

In this example, updating `topCardIndex` would change which cards are visible.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let cards = Card.data.shuffled()
    @State var topCardIndex: Int = 0
    // There might be a better way to do this
    var visibleCards: [Card] { Array(cards.dropFirst(topCardIndex).prefix(3))
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                AnimatedBackground()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .blur(radius: 25)
                VStack {
                    //Top Stack
                    TopStack()
                    ZStack {
                        ForEach(visibleCards, id: \.id) { index in
                            CardView(card: index)
                                .padding(8)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's incredibly helpful! I'm not quite sure how to get the code to iterate this visibleCards array but I'm going to keep tinkering with it

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply remove the first card at the end of your `.onEnded {}` and add a new card at the end of the array? This way you are always keeping a fixed (and rather small e.g. 5) length of `CardView`s in memory.

Obviously you would have to place the `.onEnded` after the `CardView(card: index)` code like so:

```swift
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
    let cards = Card.data.shuffled() // this should be kept in a viewModel
    @State var isHelp = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                AnimatedBackground()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .blur(radius: 25)
                VStack {
                    //Top Stack
                    Spacer()
                    TopStack()
                    //Card
                    ZStack {
                        ForEach(cards, id: \.id) { index in
                            CardView(card: index)
                                .onEnded {
                                 /* 1. do animation (see original onEnded)
                                    2. remove first element of array
                                    3. load next element into array */
                                }
//                                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10)
                                .padding(8)
                        }
                    }
                    //Bottom Stack
                    BottomStack()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```